# Regex get string except between words

Tags: regex

I have the following text in my file:

```
src="assets/images/logo.png"
```

I want to search for every occurrence of `src="assets/images/` + `"` so basically I want to exclude the file name only.

Is it possible with regex?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `.+?` to match any file name. So, the regex should be

```
src=\"assets\/images\/.+?\"
```